# StreamReader.ReadLine() returning null string in C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, python-3.x, c#-4.0, botframework

I am making a conversational weather chat bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework.

- Inside the Controller class I am calling the getWeather() method of the Weather class.
- Inside the getWeather method I am running a python script to make an API call.
- Now I am redirecting the standard output from the python script to a StreamReader object which I am reading via a string.

However the StreamReader object returns an empty string. Could anyone please help me with this?

The Python Script:

```
import requests
city = "something"
APIkey = "something"
r = requests.post('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&APPID='APIkey)
json_obj = r.json()
print(json_obj['weather'][0]['description'])
```

When I run this script in the python shell I am getting this as output:

```
haze
```

The MessagesController.cs class

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                // calculate something for us to return
                string s = activity.Text;
                Weather w = new Weather();
                s = w.getWeather(s);
                // return our reply to the user
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(s);
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
}
```

The getWeather() method inside the Weather class

```
public string getWeather(string s)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pythonInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Process python;
            StreamReader sr;
            pythonInfo.FileName = @"somepath\python.exe";
            pythonInfo.Arguments = @"somepath\file.py";
            pythonInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            pythonInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pythonInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Python Starting");
            python = Process.Start(pythonInfo);
            Debug.WriteLine("Python Started");
            sr = python.StandardOutput;
            Debug.WriteLine("passed standard output to sr");
            string text = sr.ReadLine();
            Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            Debug.WriteLine(text);
            python.WaitForExit();
            python.Close();
            sr.Close();
            return text;
        }
```

text is being returned as an empty string instead of the output as given by the python script. Please help!

Comment: have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using the ReadToEnd() method does not make a difference. Also I took care of the deadlock situation as shown above. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: What is the purpose of running python from c# ApiController?
Can't you make a web request using HttpClient - this would be much simpler and faster

Comment: Actually I have got a complicated script written out in Python, and I need someway to integrate it with the bot I am making. Sure it would be much wiser to use native methods, but this was a hail mary to see if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Are u sure the script is being executed? Try with the full path of python and the script...